# Flash AS3 - Load XML from outside web directory on the local server

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, urlloader

Is it possible for flash to access data from outside of the root directory of the server it resides.

i.e.

Root directory = /var/www/httpdocs

SWF = /var/www/httpdocs/flash/file.swf

XML = /var/www/xml/file.xml

Thanks!

Comment: Can your client's browser can access the xml path from the web?

Answer (score 2):

the urlloader is running inside the client's browser so if they can't access that xml folder from the web it wouldn't work.

in addition even if they can access the xml path via the web then it will need to be exposed via the same domain to avoid flash sandbox security issues. otherwise you will need to add a cross domain permission xml file that can be fetched (by flash) from your domain allowing access from other domains.